# Sorting a 2d array where all values are doubles in Java

Tags: java

I guess this is kind of a common question, but I looked at some other responses and couldn't get my code to work.

I have a 2d array of doubles, two columns and a bunch of rows, and I want to sort the array by the first column in ascending order.

My array is called ratio[][], and I tried this code:

```
  Arrays.sort(ratio, new Comparator<double[]>() {

    @Override
    public double compare(double[] o1, double[] o2) {
        return valueOf(o1[0]).compareTo(valueOf(o2[0]));
    }

  });
```

The compiler is finding a bunch of errors.  I've imported java.util.Arrays and java.util.Comparator. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are just comparing two double values again and again, not array of doubles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to define the ordering of your double arrays by the first element (which seems like what you are trying to do), then all you need to do is:

```
Arrays.sort(ratio, new Comparator<double[]>() {
    @Override
    public double compare(double[] o1, double[] o2) {
        return Double.compare(o1[0], o2[0]);
    }
});
```

There's no need to construct a `Double` object for each comparison (or to convert your arrays to type `Double[]`).

Answer (score 2):

Your `valueOf` is a static method of `Double` class. It should be invoked on it.

If you are just sorting the 2-D array on the basis of `first column` of each array, it would be like this: -

```
Arrays.sort(ratio, new Comparator<double[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(double[] o1, double[] o2) {
            return Double.valueOf(o1[0]).compareTo(Double.valueOf(o2[0]));
        }
});
```

And, you can use `Comparator` on type `double[]` since an `array` is an `object` only. So, you don't need to convert it to `Double[][]`.

**UPDATE**: -

- You can also use **`Double.compare(double, double)`** method as in @Ted's answer, because that will not need you to create two double objects. But, that's not going to matter much on small scale, if you are building a large application having lots of comparison, then you should definitely go this one.

Comment: That did it, I'm surprised I was that close...  Thank you!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point, but this won't sort the array.  Have a look at my answer for examples (yes, I just tried your answer it still won't sort the array)

Comment: @MadProgrammer. `I want to sort the array by the first column in ascending order.` This is what OP wants. Now you can try the code and see whether it does it. I think you misunderstood the question. Even I got it wrong the first time. :)

Comment: @RohitJain I am missing something, sleep.  I've being trying to sort the inner array not the outer :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer. Haha :) Happens. Now you can improve your post, so that I can remove the downvote.

Comment: @RohitJain No worries +1 to you though ;)

Comment: There's no good reason to generate two `Double` objects for every comparison. This will create a lot of garbage and will be quite a bit slower than comparing the primitive `double` values.

Comment: @TedHopp. But you can't invoke `compareTo` on primitive right?

Comment: @TedHopp. Ah! mistook some other answer as your's. Sorry. Your's is better.

Comment: i dont think you can use o1[0] - o2[0] even if you cast it to an int, because of truncation of numbers smaller than 1.  In my answer i changed it to double c = o1.one - o2.one; return c < 0.0 ? -1 : c > 0.0 ? 1 : 0;

Comment: @MadProgrammer. o.O Maddy. You can't return the difference of a double value. Typecasting will be needed, that will truncate the values, thus giving inappropriate sorting. ;)

Comment: No worries about trying to use `compareTo` on primitives. :) Regarding your edit--using `o1[0] - o2[0]` has several defects: it can overflow; it can fall victim to catastrophic round-off errors; it does not correctly handle differences less than 1; and it does not correctly handle `NaN` values. Much better to use `Double.compare(double,double)`.

Comment: @TedHopp. Yeah I edited the answer after realising that. Partial faults on MadProgrammer. He sent me on the wrong way. I think he didn't slept the last night. lol ;)

Comment: @TedHopp Nice points, I wish I understood half of it, but a fair point none the less.

Comment: @MadProgrammer. haha :) See you in next post. ;)

Answer (score 0):

just a suggestion..

```
  class Row {
      public double one;
      public double two;
  }  

  Row[] rows = // create this

  Arrays.sort(rows, new Comparator<Row>() {
      public int compare(Row o1, Row o2) {
          double c = o1.one - o2.one;
          return c < 0.0 ? -1 : c > 0.0 ? 1 : 0;
      }
  }
```

Comment: This can have a problem with underflow/overflow and does not correctly handle `NaN`.

Comment: Ahhh... Also, if MadProgrammer's answer works I retract my answer :)

Comment: @catchpolenet. No, his answer is not going to work. It will throw an Exception at runtime.

Comment: @catchpolenet. You're very first line is incorrect. We can create `Comparator` on `double[]`. An array is an object right?

Comment: @RohitJain Apart from sorting the wrong array index (:P), why would it have thrown an exception?

Comment: @MadProgrammer. You declared your array as: - `double[][] arr = new double[0][0]`. See that `0's` at the end. Source of Exception.

Comment: @MadProgrammer. Lol:) You need to sleep. Rest your body. Don't become literally a mad programmer. ;) :D

Comment: @RohitJain Fair point, I had corrected, but I was just trying it to compile :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer. Completely working code is needed on SO bro. :)

Comment: @RohitJain Thanks for hammering it out for me, it is appropriated :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer sorting on column one? i thought that was the aim? "I want to sort the array by the first column in ascending order."

Comment: @catchpolenet yes it is, just ignore me, I'm sleep deprived ;)